# What does Instruction.Offset represent in mono.cecil?

Tags: .net, debug-symbols, il, mono.cecil

Can I interpret this as the line number in the source file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Offset` is the position of the instruction inside the method IL. It's used to implement branches.

To get line numbers you must use either **Mono.Cecil.[Pdb|Mdb].dll** (MS or Mono debugging symbols) and the `SequencePoint`. If that's what you're after then look at Gendarme [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/blob/master/gendarme/framework/Gendarme.Framework/Symbols.cs) for symbols.

Answer (score 3):

This is the number of bytes into the IL-body of the method.